# Returning to previous switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want to ask. 
How to return to the main switch case if user choose 5?
I can't figure out what to use or is there another way of doing this?
Here is my code:

```java
System.out.println("<<INTI Max>>\n");
System.out.println("1.Stock Maintenence");
System.out.println("2.Create Order");
System.out.println("3.View Order");
System.out.println("4.View Back Order");
System.out.println("5.Exit\n");
System.out.print("Option : ");
option = sc.nextInt();
```

```java
//1st Switch Case
switch(option){
    case 1: System.out.println("<<INTI Max>>\n");
        System.out.println("1.Add New Stock Item");
        System.out.println("2.Edit New Stock Item");
        System.out.println("3.Delete Stock Item");
        System.out.println("4.Search Stock Item");
        System.out.println("5.Return to Main\n");
        System.out.print("Option : ");
        option2 = sc.nextInt();
```

```java
//2nd Switch Case
switch(option2){
    case 1: break;
    case 2: break;
    case 3: break;
    case 4: break;
    case 5: System.out.println("<<INTI Max>>\n");
            System.out.println("Returning to Main Page");
                return;
}//END 2nd Swtich Caseenter code here
```

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a `while` loop?

Comment: Or wrap this code in a function and in case 5 recall the function.

Comment: Ok guys, got it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip